# Eclipse/CDT/MinGW/GDB Watching objects while debugging

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

When I debug C++ app in Visual Studio, I can watch all object's fields when I point a cursor on it or add it to "Watch". Can I do the same in Eclipse/CDT?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.  During debugging, in the Debug Perspective, on the Variables tab, you can click on any variable in scope and look at it's fields.  You can then right click on it and add it as a watch variable and it will show up on the Expressions tab where you can see all of it's fields as well.